# Porque mi variable nombreFichero se cambia a None en la función Guardar? py

Tags: python, tkinter, function, variables-globales

Estoy intentando crear un bloc de notas en python. De momento tengo des opciones creadas, guardar como, que funciona bien y guardar que aqui es donde me da el error. Cree una variable que se llama nombreFichero, esta empieza en None y la cambio en Guardar como substituyendo el None por el nombre que el usuario especifique. Cuando yo le doy a guardar si nombreFichero es igual a None me llevara a guardar como y esto funciona bien hasta que le das por segunda vez a guardar, que debería tener dentro el nombre del fichero creado al haber pasado por Guardar como, pero como se ve en ese print sigue teniendo el valor None y llama siempre a Guardar como. Aqui les dejo el código:

````
from tkinter import filedialog
from io import open

#Aqui creo la ventana
root=Tk()
miFrame=Frame()
miFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
miFrame.config(width="1910", height="980")

global nombreFichero
nombreFichero=None

#Creo la función Guardar como
def GuardarComo(text):
    files = [("Documento de texto", "*.txt"),
            ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")]
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension = files)
    nombreFichero=file #hasta aqui bn, aqui es donde cambio el valor de nombreFichero
    filetext= str(text.get(1.0,END))
    try:
        file.write(filetext)
        file.close()
    except AttributeError:
        print("SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR")
        return

#Creo la función guardar
def SaveFile(text):
    #Aqui es donde da el fallo, siempre que llega aqui llega None (la primera vez esta bien que llegue, ya que no lo hemos cambiado, pero la segunda vez que guardas ya no debería ser none)
    print(nombreFichero)
    if nombreFichero == None:
        GuardarComo(text)
    else:
        guardado=text.get(1.0, END)
        print(guardado)



texto = Text(miFrame, width="1900", height="980")
texto.place(x=0, y=0)

barraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)

archivoMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Guardar", command=lambda:SaveFile(texto))
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Guardar como", command=lambda:GuardarComo(texto))
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=archivoMenu)

root.mainloop() ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando esta linea se ejecuta `nombreFichero=file` en realidad estás creando una variable nueva dentro de la función. En ningún momento alteras la variable fuera de la función.

La solución a esto es indicarle a Python que cada vez que le asignes un valor a la variable `nombreFichero`, afecte a la variable fuera de la función (que es global). Esto se puede lograr con `global`. Tu función quedaría así:

```
def GuardarComo(text):
    global nombreFichero

    [el resto de tu código aqui]
```

Si quieres saber más y entender mejor como funcionan el ambito local (dentro de la función) y global (fuera de cualquier función) te recomiendo esta lectura: https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/#0-%C3%A1mbito-de-una-variable

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de esta forma